# Linux Commad Line Zip with Regex

Tags: regex, linux, command-line, zip

I have thousands of jpg files that are all called 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg and so on. I need to zip up a range of them and I thought I could do this with regex, but so far haven't had any luck.

Here is the command

```
 zip images.zip '[66895-105515]'.jpg
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Since regular expressions only match characters, the regular expression to match the number range based on the characters would be particularly monstrous!  

(6(6(89[5-9]|9[0-9]{2})|[7-9][0-9]{3})|[7-9][0-9]{4}|10([0-4][0-9]{3}|5([0-4][0-9]{2}|5(0[0-9]|1[0-5]))))  

In your case, what your regular expression is saying is:  
`[      # Match any of the following characters:`  
`6689    # Any of these characters`  
`5-1     # Or anything in the ascii range of the character '5' to the character '1'`  
`05515   # Or any of these characters`  
`]`

Edit: Ugh, formatting :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am very sure that is not possible to match number ranges like this with regular expressions (digit ranges, yes, but not whole multi-digit numbers), as regular expressions work on the character level. However, you can use the "seq" command to generate the list of files and use "xargs" to pass them to "zip":

```
seq --format %g.jpg 66895 105515 | xargs zip images.zip
```

I tested the command with a bunch of dummy files under Linux and it works fine.

Comment: Recent version of OS X have the `seq` tool (just checked on 10.11, and another [an answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101337/how-in-os-x-to-get-seq-command-line-functionality) mentions that the command is available at least as early as in OS X 10.8.5).

Answer (score 6):

Use in conjunction with ls and bash range (`{m..n}`) operator like this:

```
ls {66895..105515}".jpg" 2>/dev/null | zip jpegs -@
```

Comment: Yes using find it was including all files that's why I edited my answer to include files in numeric range: `{66895..105515}`

Comment: This is such a good one!

Answer (score 4):

You need to pipe some stuff - list the files, filter by the regex, zip up each listed file.

```
ls | grep [66895-10551] | xargs zip images.zip
```

Edit: Whoops, didn't test with multi-digit numbers. As denisw mentions, this method won't work.

Comment: @Ian R.B I used this command and it worked perfectly for me. I used this by changing to my requirement.  `ls | grep eazybi.* | xargs zip eazybi-logs.zip`. Thanks