# How in OS/X to get 'seq' command-line functionality?

Tags: macos, shell, gnu, sequences, seq

I'm still on Snow Leopard (I know...) so forgive if this is fixed in one of the later versions of OS/X, but I want to do standard "seq" aka:

```
for i in `seq 1 100` ; do
  cat /whatever > $i.txt ;
done
```

I thought installing GNU tools would do it, but apparently not.

Comment: Does `for i in {1..100}` work to you?

Comment: You can probably use `$(command)` rather than the backtick syntax that I'm too lazy to figure out how to show in a comment.  It's a bit easier to read, and it can be nested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my mac both of these work (OS X 10.8.5)

```
Andreas-Wederbrands-MacBook-Pro:~ raven$ for i in {1..10}; do echo $i; done
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
Andreas-Wederbrands-MacBook-Pro:~ raven$ for i in `seq 1 10`; do echo $i; done
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: It looks like you're on a newer version of OS/X. I get "seq command not found," however, the {1..10} works! Thanks!

Comment: OS X 10.5 does not have `seq`. OS X 10.5 was the last version for the PowerMac's (PowerPC). Snow Leopard is OS X 10.6. It was available for Intel's.

Answer (score 3):

In Snow Leopard, you can use the `jot` command, which can produce sequential data like `seq` (and more, see the man page for details).

```
$ jot 5
1
2
3
4
5
$ jot 3 5
5
6
7
```

Comment: Is `jot` standards-compliant? (Granted, `seq` isn't either, but it'd be nice to point folks towards tools that will be available wherever their shell is).

Comment: I don't think there is a standards-compliant answer; brace expansion  and C-style loops are absent from POSIX. `jot` is nice to know, as it's the `seq`-equivalent program available in OS X 10.6 (`seq` itself ships with 10.8+, maybe 10.7 as well). Anyway, the accepted answer and yours covers the `bash` options well enough.

Comment: I _do_ cover the POSIX option near the bottom of my answer; it's the third code block.

Comment: For the curious. `jot` is a BSD utility. Available on all BSD systems and whatever borrowed from that (such OSX). AFAIK it's not available on any other UNIX system (Solaris, AIX, etc) or Linux, although it can often be installed as a package. It is somewhat unfortunate that the GNU folk created seq(1), instead of adopting/duplicating `jot`, which had already been around for a number of years...

Comment: I can't seem to get `jot` to count backwards in steps of `0.1`. It results in ***`jot: bad precision value`***. Does it allow increments/decrements of decimal values? The man pages don't seem to be clear about it.

Answer (score 2):

No need for a tool such as `seq` -- bash (like ksh and zsh) has syntax built-in:

```
# bash 3.x+
for ((i=0; i<100; i++)); do
  ...
done
```

...or, for bash 2.04+, zsh, and ksh93:

```
i=0; while ((i++ <= 100)); do
   ...
done
```

...or, for absolutely any POSIX-compliant shell:

```
while [ $(( ( i += 1 ) <= 100 )) -ne 0 ]; do 
  ...
done
```

bash also supports expansions such as `{0..100}`, but that doesn't support variables as endpoints, whereas the for-loop syntax is more flexible.

Comment: `i=20.0; while [ $(( ( i -= 0.1 ) >= 1.0 )) -ne 0 ];` results in ***`syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0")`***. Bash is ***`GNU bash, version 3.2.17(1)-release (powerpc-apple-darwin9.0)`***.

Comment: @jww, of course it does; bash has only integer math. There's no guarantee that `seq` provides floating-point either -- on several platforms it doesn't.

Comment: But `seq` allows us to do it: `for i in $(seq -f "%.1f" 20.0 -0.1 1.0)`.

Comment: @jww, not all versions of `seq`. (It's not a standardized command, so this should be no surprise).

Comment: ...though looking at common implementations, that *is* more widely available functionality than I would have guessed. If there were significant call for it, the right tool to use in emulating it would probably be `awk`.

Comment: Thanks Charles. I tried `jot` since this is an OS X-only script. I think I might need to open another question about this.... Shell programming is the pits...

Answer (score 0):

Or, just add this to your bash profile:

```
function seq {
  if [ $1 > $2 ] ; then
    for ((i=$1; i<=$2; i++))
      do echo $i
    done
  else
    for ((i=$1; i>=$2; i--))
      do echo $i
    done
  fi
}
```

It's not that hard.

Comment: Using `[ $1 > $2 ]` is wrong here -- it's actually a redirection (to the file named in `$2`), not a math comparison. Use `(( $1 > $2 ))` instead, since you're already assuming bash-only syntax, or `[ "$1" -gt "$2" ]` for something more portable.

Comment: ...and speaking of bash-only syntax, consider avoiding the `function` keyword. `seq() {` is the POSIX-defined way to declare functions, and thus a better habit to be in if you need to write portable code.